# Should I use jQuery UI full or custom?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Sometimes I just got tired of choosing the bundle. One is hassle, another is while using third-party scripts, I need to make sure the custom build has the widget support.

On the other hand, I am also concern about the size of the javascript when a full build is used instead of custom build. Is that negligible? Those widgets that I want is already 100k+, while the full build is 200k+.

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't see the question here. You've outlined the two issues - ease of configuration vs. unecessary bloat. How to balance these is entirely context-specific - in your project, is speed of development more important than client optimization?

Comment: Use a full build in Development, when going live, just deselect the ones you didnt use. Are you complaining it takes about 4secs? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that really depends on what you need.

but...(and thats what i do)
i'll suggest to use the full jqueryui for development mode, for the ease of not wondering and deciding what modules you are about to use while in developemnt...

when you go production, just cut the things you haven't used using the jqueryui custom builder...

another solution for production is to use the minified version of both jquery and jqueryui (the full version) right from google's/microsoft's cdn. most clients probably already have those scripts and stylesheets cached within the browser, and if not, google/ms cdn will serve it to them and u wont have to worry about your server serving those pages.

[google's cdn](http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery)

[microsoft's cdn](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx)

Comment: also this isn't really a programming question

Comment: well. it does concerns web-development and best practice consultation

Comment: Depends if "development" also includes QA/testing. It's essential IMO that what gets tested is identical to what gets deployed to production.